# How not to let python requests calculate content-length and use the provided one?

Tags: python, python-requests, content-length, http-content-length

We have some  custom module where we have redefined `open`, `seek`, `read`, `tell` functions to read only a part of file according to the arguments.

But, this logic overrides the default `tell` and python `requests` is trying to calculate the **content-length** which involves using `tell()`, which then redirects to our custom `tell` function and the logic is somewhere buggy and  returns a wrong value. And I tried some changes, it throws error.

Found the following from models.py of requests:

```
 def prepare_content_length(self, body):
        if hasattr(body, 'seek') and hasattr(body, 'tell'):
            body.seek(0, 2)
            self.headers['Content-Length'] = builtin_str(body.tell())
            body.seek(0, 0)
        elif body is not None:
            l = super_len(body)
            if l:
                self.headers['Content-Length'] = builtin_str(l)
        elif (self.method not in ('GET', 'HEAD')) and (self.headers.get('Content-Length') is None):
            self.headers['Content-Length'] = '0'
```

For now, I am not able to figure out where's the bug and stressed out to investigate more and fix it. And everything else work except content-length calculation by python requests.

So, I have created my own definition for finding content-length. And I have included the value in requests header. But, the request is still preparing the content-length and throwing error.

How can I restrict not preparing content-length and use the specified content-length?

Comment: Well, you are changing standard functions and methods. How can you expect things to work correctly?

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini Hi, Yes, you are right. But, this is required for us to split a file into multiple parts and upload. Well, it's been there for so long. And recently, we have switched from urllib2 to requests, so we came across this error now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Requests lets you modify a request before sending. See [Prepared Requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#prepared-requests).

For example:

```
from requests import Request, Session

s = Session()

req = Request('POST', url, data=data, headers=headers)
prepped = req.prepare()

# do something with prepped.headers
prepped.headers['Content-Length'] = your_custom_content_length_calculation()

resp = s.send(prepped, ...)
```

If your session has its own configuration (like cookie persistence or connection-pooling), then you should use `s.prepare_request(req)` instead of `req.prepare()`.

Comment: Oh yes, I read it. Bus mistook in wrong way. Now it's clear..thanks!..:)