# Requests python custom content-Length

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, urllib

Is want to send the content-length header with incorrect body length

I did try use [Prepared Requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36458634/how-not-to-let-python-requests-calculate-content-length-and-use-the-provided-one)

But when trying set

`prepped.headers['Content-Length'] = 2`

And set this body for request

`testtest`

it will send `te` only and i want to send `testtest` with `Conten-Length: 2`

Comment: Are you sure it's not the receiving web server that only reads the Content-Length number of bytes in the request? I.e. your code might be sending `testtest`, but the server might only be reading the first two bytes?

Comment: Yes. 
The server did read the body set in content-length
Thank you for that